# Flutter app(android) not working on real device in release mode

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've been building a demo app to practice flutter, the app's running perfectly fine in the emulator as well as on real devices when connected. But now, I've been trying to run the APK file on my mobile and it seems to not work. I can log in to the app meaning the internet permission is working. But when it comes to the home screen which pulls data from a server, the app does not work. Maybe there's something wrong in the code relevant, but I can't seem to fix it.

I've attached the code for the home screen as well, the provider part is the thing that is having issues. **AND ALSO THE DATABASE HAS THE DATA MEANING THE LIST IS NOT EMPTY AT ALL**

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './new_enquiry_screen.dart';
import '../providers/enquiries_provider.dart';
import '../screens/new_enquiry_screen.dart';
import '../widgets/drawer_widget.dart';
import '../widgets/follow_up_list_tile_widget.dart';

class EnquiryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const EnquiryScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: DrawerWidget(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: const TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Follow Ups'),
              Tab(text: 'Leads'),
              Tab(text: 'Past'),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Enquiries',
          ),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider<EnquiriesProvider>.value(
              value: EnquiriesProvider(),
              child: Consumer<EnquiriesProvider>(
                builder: (_, provider, child) {
                  int length = provider.enquiries.length;
                  return length == 0
                      ? Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        )
                      : ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: length,
                          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                            return FollowUpListTileWidget(
                              provider.enquiries.elementAt(index),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                },
              ),
            ),
            const Center(
              child: Text('Leads Up'),
            ),
            const Center(
              child: Text('Past Up'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(NewEnquiryScreen.routeName);
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            size: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/enquiry.dart';

class FollowUpListTileWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const FollowUpListTileWidget(this._enquiry, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final Enquiry _enquiry;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 10,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 5.0),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          child: Text(
            _enquiry.name.characters.first.toUpperCase(),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
        title: Text(_enquiry.name),
        subtitle: FittedBox(child: Text(_enquiry.email)),
        trailing: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.phone,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.whatsapp),
            ),
            IconButton(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please remove the all-caps from your question and title. They are unnecessary and annoying to read.

Answer (score 1):

try to run app in debug mode in real device, if it is working then check in manifest file you have given internet permission or not inside `android/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml` by default in debug mode internet permission is already exits and most important please remove all caps from your question title as it is very difficult to read.

Comment: I've given permission already.  And the app runs also fine on real device when it's in debugging phase.

Comment: is your server using https?

Comment: It's https based @CarlosSandoval

Answer (score 0):

\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml file to add a permission
use in networking

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur12x.png)